# %REQUEST_URI without slash in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have lots of files starting with "display-", like:

```
display-profile.php
display-photos.php
display-comments.php
...
```

I want to keep those names for organization (as there are files with other prefixes), but I want to remove "display-" from my URLs.
I was going to use .htaccess to check if `display-%{REQUEST_URI}` is a file, but that environment variable has a slash "/" at the begin.

How do I get the `%{REQUEST_URI}` without the slash at the beginning? Or, is there any other way to check this?

Thank you. I use Apache on a Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/display-$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !display-([^/]+).php$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ display-$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or, another option:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/display-%1 -f
RewriteRule . display-%1 [L,QSA]
```

Possibly shorter:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/display-$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ display-$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or even:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/display-$1 -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ display-$1 [L,QSA]
```